# Unable to convert array according to date time value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array named $itemIds and it consists of the following datas. The key is the items id and the value is the date time that can be converted to a readable date.What I want to do is simply sort the order of the array according to the value (time). I'm totally new to php and some examples or tips would be great ! I would love to hear from you.

```
Array
(
    [10477] => 1508898726
    [10549] => 1508898744
    [10891] => 1508898752
)
```

If I use this code I get the following data from the print_r.

```
if (isset($itemIds)) {
    $time = array();
    foreach ($itemIds as $key => $val) {
        print_r($key.'=>'.date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $val));
    }
}
```

The problem starts from here.I want to sort(asc & desc) the $itemsIds according to the date time.

```
10477 => 10/25/2017 11:32:06
10549 => 10/25/2017 11:32:24
10891 => 10/25/2017 11:32:32
```

I want to sort the data  then use array_keys($shopIds) to change it like the following data

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10477
    [1] => 10549
    [2] => 10891
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easier approach would be to sort the data and then flip it so the keys are values. If you look at your data you are initially dealing with actual timestamps from what I can see. Use them, don't change them to strings. I say this because you are just causing yourself to do extra work without any reason and introducing a layer of complexity that is not needed. Instead I would do the following:

```
$array = [
    10477 => 1508898726,
    10549 => 1508898744,
    10891 => 1508898752,
];
arsort($array);
$sorted_array = array_values(array_flip($array));
```

This is easy to read and does not involve the extra function. The result you are left with is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10477
    [1] => 10549
    [2] => 10891
)
```

A little explanation:

I am using `arsort()` or `asort()` (based on the direction you want to sort) in order to sort based on the values in the array.

Then I use `array_flip()` on the array in order to swap the keys and values.

And last I am using `array_keys()` to reset the indexes in the array and maintain its sort.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the most Helpful solution !